# Do not include section in TOC in pandoc

Tags: latex, pandoc

I am using [this](https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown) thesis template. It includes the abstract, acknowledgements, list of figures... in the [table of contents](https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown/blob/master/output/thesis.pdf). According to the university guidelines my TOC should start with Chapter 1 Introduction and not list abstract, acknowledgements... .

In latex you can just use `\section*` however using `.unnumbered` in pandoc results in that section still being included.

What is the cleanest way to exclude the sections before the introduction chapter from the TOC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `-H header.tex` as an Pandoc option.

My workaround is appending:

`\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline`

to `header.tex` directly.

I wrote the same issue on GitHub: https://github.com/chdemko/pandoc-latex-unlisted/issues/1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `{.unlisted}`.

Typically,

```
# Intro{.unlisted}

# Chapter 1
```

compiled with

`pandoc test.md --toc -s -o test.html` will give you

[image]

with the relevant `html` bit:

```
<body>
<nav id="TOC" role="doc-toc">
<ul>
<li><a href="#chapter-1">Chapter 1</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1 class="unlisted" id="intro">Intro</h1>
<h1 id="chapter-1">Chapter 1</h1>
</body>
```

[Source](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/toc-unlisted.html), [Doc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#heading-identifiers)

Answer (score 3):

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1762) about this in pandoc.

To remove `{.unnumbered}` headers from the LaTeX TOC, you can meanwhile use the [pandoc-latex-unlisted filter](https://pypi.org/project/pandoc-latex-unlisted/).

```
$ pip install pandoc-latex-unlisted
$ pandoc --filter pandoc-latex-unlisted input.md -o output.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however using your filter I get the following error: `Chapter 1.
! Undefined control sequence.
\addcontentsline #1#2#3->\oldaddcontentsline 
                                             {#1}{#2}{#3}
l.327 \chapter{Introduction}\label{introduction}}
`. Do you have an idea what the problem could be here?
See [here](https://github.com/tompollard/phd_thesis_markdown/blob/master/Makefile) for my full build command.

Comment: not sure, I didn't write the filter myself... maybe helps inspecting the generated TeX with `-s -t latex`...

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine `.unlisted` with `.unnumbered` to achieve this, as stated in [Pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#heading-identifiers).

Example:

```markdown
# Abstract {.unnumbered .unlisted}

# Acknowledgements {.unnumbered .unlisted}

# Chapter 1
```